# Search across multiple indexes at once in Whoosh

Tags: python, whoosh

I have a few indexes located in the same directory as part of a storage object.

```
from whoosh.filedb.filestore import FileStorage
storage = FileStorage("../indexdir")
ix_1 = storage.open_index(indexname='ind_1')
ix_2 = storage.open_index(indexname='ind_2')
```

I want to be able to search a query through BOTH indexes at the same time and not just one of them. Is it possible to do that without having a single index?
I can append the results of each index one after the other but I can't figure out how to sort them or if that is even possible.

Comment: Were you able to do it ? I am also looking to search from multiple index at the same time. Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, no unfortunately I wasn't able to :(

Comment: Oh. If I could find anything I will definitely share with you.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated on March 8th, 2021**

Based on comments

### Loading modules

```
from whoosh.index import create_in
from whoosh.fields import *
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser

import pandas as pd
```

### Defining search term

```
TERM = "second"
```

### Creating indices for this example

```
schema = Schema(title=TEXT(stored=True), path=ID(stored=True), content=TEXT)
ix1 = create_in("indexdir1", schema)

schema = Schema(title=TEXT, path=ID(stored=True), content=TEXT(stored=True))
ix2 = create_in("indexdir2", schema)

writer1 = ix1.writer()
writer2 = ix2.writer()

for writer in [writer1, writer2]:
    writer.add_document(title=u"First document", path=u"/a",
                        content=u"This is the first document we've added! Not the second")
    writer.add_document(title=u"Second document", path=u"/b",
                        content=u"The second one is even more interesting than the first one!")
    writer.add_document(title=u"Third document", path=u"/c",
                        content=u"You know... This is also different from the second one!")
    writer.commit()
```

### Searching by the term

```
results = []

parser = QueryParser("title", ix1.schema)
query = parser.parse(TERM)
results += list(ix1.searcher().search(query))

parser = QueryParser("content", ix1.schema)
query = parser.parse(TERM)
results += list(ix2.searcher().search(query))
```

So far your results are

```
print(results)

[<Hit {'path': '/b', 'title': 'Second document'}>, <Hit {'content': "This is the first document we've added! Not the second", 'path': '/a'}>, <Hit {'content': 'You know... This is also different from the second one!', 'path': '/c'}>, <Hit {'content': 'The second one is even more interesting than the first one!', 'path': '/b'}>]
```

Although the results are together, they are not ordered by anything.

### Transforming it into a dictionary data structure

```
result = {"path": [], "title": [], "content": []}
fields = ["path", "title", "content"]

for dct in results:
    for field in fields:
        result[field].append(dct.get(field, None))
```

### Creating a pandas dataframe with the results

```
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)
```

The dataframe is:

```
  path            title                                            content
0   /b  Second document                                               None
1   /a             None  This is the first document we've added! Not th...
2   /c             None  You know... This is also different from the se...
3   /b             None  The second one is even more interesting than t...
```

**Note** Where you get **None** is because it doesn't match with the search

### Grouping the results by "path" and counting results

```
groups = df.groupby(["path"]).count()
```

The groups

```
      title  content
path                
/a        0        1
/b        1        1
/c        0        1
```

### Creating a score column

```
groups["score"] = groups["title"] + groups["content"]
```

With the score column

```
      title  content  score
path                       
/a        1        1      2
/b        0        1      1
/c        0        1      1
```

### Sorting results by score

```
print(groups.sort_values("score", ascending=False))
```

```
      title  content  score
path                       
/b        1        1      2
/a        0        1      1
/c        0        1      1
```

**Note** Although is in the same order as the one printed before it may not be the case in the real world

Finally, you can iterate through the dataframe and present your results.

**End of update**

---

> **Note** You will find the first answer below. Specifically for the "**at once**" part. After some comments, I updated the post and decided to keep this here, because it might be useful.

---

Why don't use `concurrent.futures` for that?

### Starting

```
import concurrent.futures
from whoosh.filedb.filestore import FileStorage

storage = FileStorage("../indexdir")
ix_1 = storage.open_index(indexname='ind_1')
ix_2 = storage.open_index(indexname='ind_2')

ixs = [ix_1, ix_2]

TERM = "TERM TO SEARCH"
```

### Defining search function

```
def search_things(ix, term):
    with ix.searcher() as searcher:
        query = QueryParser("content", ix.schema).parse(term)
        results = searcher.search(query, terms=True)
    return results
```

### Parallelizing

```
# using two workers because there are two indices
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 2) as executor:
   future_to_search = {executor.submit(search_things, ix, TERM): ix for ix in ixs}

   for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_search):
       s = future_to_search[future]
       try:
          data = future.result()
       except Exception as exc:
          print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (s, exc))
       else:
          print('Search (%r) finished => %d' % (s, data))
```

You might need to adapt it for your needs.

Comment: Parallelism is hardly the issue here,  the problem is in the search results. This wouldn't work on search_page. Also, the sorting relevancy would be screwed up.

Comment: I think the the optimal solution will somehow involve searching multiple indexes as if they were one.

Comment: Well, the question was how to search them at the same time. If there is the need for joining results, then having two indexes maybe is wrong.

Comment: Read the last part of the question: "I can append the results of each index one after the other but I can't figure out how to sort them or if that is even possible". The problem with having one monolithic index is that it doesn't scale very well. You can concurrently search multiple index, but that wouldn't solve the issue of having to sort them, especially if the search is paginated.